# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, laravel

I get an error

`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on controller`

Below is my **controller**

```
public function showIndex()
{
    $data['news'] = News::getAll();

    foreach ($data['news'] as $key => $value) {
        $data['news'][$key]['category'] = News::getCategory($value->id_berita);
    }

    return View::make('pages.news.main')
        ->with('title', 'News')
        ->with($data);
}
```

This is my **model**

```
public static function getAll()
{
    $queryResult = DB::table('berita')
    ->leftJoin('admin', 'berita.post_author', '=', 'admin.id')
    ->select('id_berita', 'judul', 'post_date', 'aktif', 'fullname', 'post_author')
    ->orderBy('id_berita', 'desc')
   ->paginate(3);

return $queryResult;
}

public static function getCategory()
{
    $queryResult = DB::table('news_in_category')
        ->join('menu_website', 'menu_website.id', '=', 'news_in_category.category_id')
        ->select('menu_website.id', 'title')
       ->get();

    return $queryResult;
}
```

and this is my **view**

```
@if ($news)
    @foreach ($news as $key => $value)

       @if ($news->category)

           @foreach ($news->category as $key_cat => $cat)
               {{ $cat->id }}
           @endforeach

       @endif

    @endforeach
@endif
```

For every news have one on more than one category, How can I fix this problem ? Please help me. I am using laravel 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this by changing

```
$data['news'][$key]['category'] = News::getCategory($value->id_berita);
```

to

```
$data['news'][$key]->category = News::getCategory($value->id_berita);
```